# How to fix DispatchQueue problem in Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

After updating Xcode and Swift 5, this code not work. Can anyone please tell me how to fix it?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    if let url  = NSURL(string: (mindata["img"] as? String)!), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            cell.img.image = UIImage(data: data)
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: "does not work" isn't a sufficient description of your issue. Please [edit] your question and provide a clear description of in what way this code doesn't work. Include any error messages if any. BTW - do not use `NSData` in Swift 3 or later. Use `Data`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to render an Image into a Cell's ImageView by using Async Dispatch Queue, right? If what I said is correct, could you try this code instead?

```swift
    if let url = URL(string: mindata["img"]) {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOfURL: url)

            if data == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.img.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            } else {
                print("Data is Nil")
            }
        } catch {
            //error from Data(contentsOfUrl to catch
        }
    } else {
        // the URL was bad!
    }
```

Reference: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-load-a-string-from-a-website-url

Comment: If this is a remote URL then do not use this approach. Only do this will a local file URL. You also need a `try` and you should check to see if `data` is `nil` or not.

Comment: That's true. I will edit to a more generic way. Thank You for the advice.

Comment: I edited the code. You can use guard or if-else. I prefer Guard in case of when you really want to do when the situation is .none and handle the situation and break the process of logic. I used if-else here because handling Nil situation is important as .some value.

Comment: i get this error Cannot subscript a value of type 'NSDictionary' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: @OsamaAltmeme Don't use NSDictionary in Swift, use the native dictionary type instead.